# How can i make a container of objects and how can i use it in other file

Tags: java, arrays, object, arraylist

I basicly have an array list in my main class

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List escenariosLi = new ArrayList<Escenario>();
    String a = "";
    escenariosLi.add(0,new Escenario(a, a, a, a, a, a));
}
```

And i need to use this array in another file where i have `Escenario` class

```java
switch (slot){        
    case 0:
        escenariosLi.set(0,new Escenario(nombre, ce, izq, der, arr, ab));
        break;
}
```

I've also tried creating the `index[0]`

Comment: Are you talking about arrays or `ArrayList`s? --- Thinking in "files" when using an OO-language is a recipe for disaster. I would recommend reading some beginner's tutorials, e.g. [this one at `oracle.com`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

Comment: I know how to do it in a siingle file. But i was asked to make it separated... nothing i can do. Its for a university project. For you to understand, i have a simulator where i need to describe scenarios. This scenarios have `name` and a `descriptions of the 4 directions`. I want to make an array of 10 `scenarios` objects. And i need to be able to change any of this scenarios at any time. So i made an array list and i want to be able to edit items inside the arraylist from the `Escenario.java` file

Comment: I recommend talking to your professor/supervisor. They know best how and what they want to teach you.

Comment: Thats not an option : / hes not someone you can talk with. He doesnt listen to students.

Comment: how do you want to use it?

Answer (score -1):

To access the escenariosLi ArrayList in another class make it a public static field in the main class:

```
public class MainClass {
    public static List<Escenario> escenariosLi = new ArrayList<Escenario>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = "";
        escenariosLi.add(0, new Escenario(a, a, a, a, a, a));
    }
}
```

In the other class:

```
public class OtherClass {
    public void someMethod() {
        // You can access escenariosLi from MainClass like MainClass.escenariosLi
        // e.g., MainClass.escenariosLi.set(0, new Escenario(nombre, ce, izq, der, arr, ab));
    }
}
```